# Setting up headless Raspberry Pi Zero W with Bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

So, I've went through many posts of setting up bluetooth for either Pi Zero W or Pi 3.
None of them worked out for me.

This is how far I've gotten:

1)

`mgjo5899@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-10-19 05:58:46 UTC; 19min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 831 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─831 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`

2)

`mgjo5899@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[   43.071673] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   43.071824] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   43.071847] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   43.071861] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   43.071907] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  374.180434] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  374.180447] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  374.180477] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized`

3)

`mgjo5899@raspberrypi:~ $ hcitool dev
Devices:`

4)

`mgjo5899@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status hciuart.service
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-10-19 05:59:32 UTC; 20min ago
  Process: 857 ExecStart=/usr/bin/btuart (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 19 05:59:02 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART...
Oct 19 05:59:32 raspberrypi btuart[857]: Initialization timed out.
Oct 19 05:59:32 raspberrypi btuart[857]: bcm43xx_init
Oct 19 05:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 19 05:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
Oct 19 05:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 19 05:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

5)

`mgjo5899@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl start hciuart.service
Job for hciuart.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hciuart.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

I saw some posts with people saying they exchanged to new Pi Zero W and they worked out well.  Am I supposed to ask for an exchange as well?  Is that the only solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? *”Set up Bluetooth”* is very vague - are you trying to add a Bluetooth keyboard, or a speaker, or what?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being vague.  So I am trying to connect bluetooth speaker to it but could not locate the bluetooth adapter on my pi zero w through terminal.  By the way, this has been fixed after replacing it with new one.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed to be a faulty board by the seller.  I got a new one and it is working as expected.